# ddrescue backuped files from broken hdd on a larger HDD -> Partition not enlargeable

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ddrescue

Hi I backuped files from a broken 1Terrabyte hdd on a larger 4Terrabyte HDD using Ubuntu.

ddrescue -fr -i0 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdc2

This seemed to work. Back on a Windows System the 4TB HD shows the size 1TB of the saved HDD. I could not enlarge the partition with the Windows Sytem tool.

I did a checkdisk and repair on windows and than i could no longer mout the disk on Ubuntu (Filesystem error). 
After check and repair with gparted I can read the hdd again, but still windows recognizes the hdd as 4tb but there is only 1TB available no non assigned space or partition available.

Does anybody know a way to proper enlarge this partition.?

Comment: Did you try with gparted?  You would have to unmount it first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it did fix that ubuntu could not mount. But it did not fix that Windows  allows enlarging the partition.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are now readable, copy them to a "normal" partition (like on another disk drive), then delete the "weird" one and create and format a new one using standard means.